# Firebox x700 Reset to Default Not Working

Tags: networking, firewall, watchguard, firebox

I found a site that explains how to reset a Firebox 700 series back to default as you can see from this link:

https://www.hashdoc.com/documents/7502/how-to-default-a-watchguard-firebox-700-or-x700

Everything works fine. I setup a separate workstation with the IP address and load the Firebox into Loopback mode. I can open the software and set a configuration. When I go to save it, I type in the Firebox default IP (which I can ping) and the wg password, however, I can't get in. After a few seconds of "logging in" I get the following error message:

Window Title: Fireware Policy Manager
Error Message:

"A connection could not be established to the firebox 192.168.253.1. 
Connection refused: connect."

I have also tried admin as a password with the same message. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this? I have never worked with one of these before.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Firmware 7 is very old (~10 years), the management software is not on their download page or the older version download page behind a login prompt. I'm guessing you got management software 11.7 or 10.7 by mistake and they are different and can't connect. If that's not it and you do have the right management software, is there any chance you have a software firewall / antivirus program blocking your outbound connection on an uncommon port?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment WSM 7.5 works for connecting.. I'm now able to access the firebox in SysB. When I create a default config I go to upload it and can login. It tells me to save config and flash image because the image is different from the managment workstation. After the image upload it restarts. I change the managment IP to work with the trusted IP set on the Firebox. Once it restarts I try entering the new IP and password I set but it tells me to check the IP and password. That's when I realized I can't ping it. Any ideas? Did I need to change something else in the config?

Comment: On some versions, the buttons and LCD screen on the front have a menu that can show you the IP addresses set on the different interfaces - X700 looks like it has them, firmware 7.5 might not do that, but try it - see if it's actually got the IP and subnet mask you expect on interface eth1. Did you set it to do DHCP - try getting an IP address from it? Can you see the firewall policies in your saved config - there should be one present by default allowing connections from the LAN to the Firebox, but if it's missing and all traffic is being denied that would include ping and management logins.